Chip Identification - SAW part marking
would anyone know what chip this is? I thought it could be BSS123, but I am not so sure anymore, because the drain would then be connected to a feedback pin of a flyback DC-DC converter and the gate would be connected to micro (T0 (Timer/Counter0 External Counter Input)
or XCK (USART External Clock Input/Output)), and I am not sure if that is right. The second pin always seems to be grounded. The dimensions are 3.5mm by 1mm. It is on some sort of power supply board of a pressure sensor.


It is a BSS123 from Nexperia.
Marking information:

(% is the assembly location code, W in your case and 22 is a datecode)
Picture from lcsc:

